# Simple TCP Server unable to connect

Tags: python, networking, server

I'm in my intro to networking course and we are learning how to program a basic TCP server.

**My Setup:**
The assignment calls for a server that  web server that handles one HTTP request at a time. My web server should "accept and parse the HTTP request, get the requested file from the server’s file system, create an HTTP response message consisting of the requested file preceded by header lines, and then send the response directly to the client. If the requested file is not present in the server, the server should send an HTTP “404 Not Found” message back to the client."  I have the server coded in Python (see below) and as far as I can tell, the code is accurate. In the same directory I have also created a simple hello world html file so I have something to request.

**Running my server:** 
When I run the code, the terminal expected 'ready to serve...' message and listens for a connection. This is correct.

Then when I type in a URL in my browser (I've tried both http://localhost:1001 and http://localhost:1001/HelloWorld.html) the browser says its unable to connect.

[Unable to connect screen from browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXouZ.png)

I'm pretty sure I'm either not connecting to the server properly as a client or if my windows machine isn't set up properly but any advise on how to connect and get my request through to the server would be greatly appreciated.

```
#import socket module
from socket import *
import sys # In order to terminate the program

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

#Prepare a sever socket
serverPort = 1001
serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    #Establish the connection
    print('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        #Send one HTTP header line into socket
        #Fill in start
        header = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n'
        connectionSocket.send(header.encode())

        #Fill in end

        #Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())

        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        #Send response message for file not found (404)
        #Fill in start
        error = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'
        connectionSocket.send(error.encode())
        #Fill in end

        #Close client socket
        #Fill in start
        connectionSocket.close()
        #Fill in end

serverSocket.close()
sys.exit()  #Terminate the program after sending the corresponding data
```

Comment: Did you get a bind error when you ran your server? You should have. 1001 is a reserved port, like all ports below 1024.

Comment: depends what's his environment, on windows I had no issue running his script on a non-admin command line.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried running your server and it worked properly. I tried getting the python code itself using the url "http://localhost:1001/test.py" and I got back your code.

Some things you might want to check is if you have access to your server's port 1001. Since this is not a standard port, some hosts could block it. You could try using port 80 instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. After some tinkering, I found that if I use port 65535 and swap in 0.0.0.0 for my host then I can specifically get Microsoft Edge (not Chrome interestingly) to branch to my HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found error. This is at least a start although, I'm not entirely clear on why this combo of factors helped and am especially interested in knowing why chrome doesn't work. The error in my Try branch seems to be in the ' filename = message.split()[1]  ' statement. This is is odd because that statement was provided by the professor in the Lab's skeleton code.